# Why doesn't material theme break in API Level 19?

Tags: android, android-activity

I recently started learning Android programming. I learned that Android supports Material Theme starting from Android API 21.

Yesterday, I created a small test application with one activity. The activity extends Activity class. The minimum SDK is 19, target SDK is 27, compile SDK is 27.

Now I changed the theme to Material.Dialog and run the application in a Android 27 device. It worked perfectly as expected.

But, I tried to run it on an Android 19 device and I expected it wouldn't run. But it ran without error. Of course, it didn't render the Material.Dialog theme properly; it renders it like the regular dark theme. The application was fully functional.

It surprised me. Why doesn't an application that uses Material Theme break if running on an API below 21? Isn't API level 21 a hard requirement for material theme?

Also, I learned that Android is backward compatible (programs designed for older API can run on newer API.) Is it also forward compatible?

The build.gradle dependencies section looks below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

The screenshot of Android emulator of API 19 is shown below:
[image]

Comment: Backward compatibility is added through a library. And it's varying to what degree it creates backwards compatibility

Comment: @Zoe While your comment didn't answer my question, you raised another interesting question:  why would we need another library to support backward compatibility? Doesn't a higher level API already contain all the functionalities of a lower level API?

Comment: appcompat (/the support library) is the library. It calls the new api's and old api's depending on API version, that's how it works. And for material design it's more complicated though (not fully sure how that works tbh)

Comment: What is your theme name in manifest? How do you have it in styles.xml

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    </style>

Comment: Do you have AppCompat libraries in your build.gradle?

Comment: Also is this style defined in res/values or res/values-21 folder?

Comment: @SteveM  No AppCompact in build.gradle. The style is defined in res/values. I don't have res/values-21 folder.

Comment: Something must rewrite it to the pre material style. I'm not sure what though.

Comment: Even Android Studio is complaining on the style.xml file. It says "android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen requires API level 21 (current min is 19)"  However, ignoring the complaint and running the app still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I talked with one of my co-workers and he answered my question. Below is the short conversation history:

> My co-worker: Themes just affect the look and feel of an app.  So if load up the app on an API 19 device, it is expected that the app will continue to function but not display properly.
>
> Me: Thank you. I didn't use support library to have a better understanding of Android compatibility. 
>       So based on your answer, technically, my application is supposed to function properly even at API 10. Right? (But not render properly.)
>
> My co-worker: yes, it should

So, while the https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html says "The material theme is only available in Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above.", it shouldn't be interpreted as "If an app utilizes material theme, it wouldn't work at an API level below 21 and break". It should be interpreted as "It may not render properly at an API level below 21, but still functions correctly."